# flex sprite textarea textrange

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, sprite, textrange

in flex,I have a textarea control
i like to select some text in textarea.
when mouse releases then selected text will be hilighted to GREEN RECTANGLE as sprite.
can anybody help ??

Answer (score 0):

Try flex's TextRange object to get selected text of textArea and to change selected text.